# transfer rewrite rule from apache to nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a problem with two rewrites transfering a sito from an apache hosting to an nginx hosting.  I've tried reading online, this is the best that i've come up with, unfortunately I have little practice with regexp and rewrites on nginx, please help.

apache rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$    news_dett.php?l=$1&par=$2&titolo=$3 [L]
```

result apache

```
exampleSite/news/it/44/Title_Of_the_news.html
```

apache rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^Research-and-develop\.html$     researchdevelop?l=$1 [L]
```

result apache

```
exampleSite/Research-and-develop.html
```

nginx rewrite

```
location /news {
     rewrite ^/news http://$http_host/news_dett.php?l=$1&par=$2&titolo=$3 redirect;
    }
```

result nginx

Clicking on link `exampleSite/news/it/44/Title_Of_the_news.html` we go to
  `exampleSite/news_dett.php?l=&par=&titolo=`

In fact this doesn't work at all

nginx rewrite

```
location /Research {
            rewrite ^/Research-and-develop\.html$ http://$http_host/researchdevelop?l=$1 redirect;
    }
```

result nginx

clicking on link `exampleSite/Research-and-develop.html`
we go to    `exampleSite/researchdevelop.php?l=`

Can you help set the correct rewrite mode for nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Your `/news` rewrite is missing the captures for `$1` and `$2`. The scheme and server parts are unnecessary when redirecting to the same server. Also, `last` performs an internal redirect, which avoids exposing the rewrite to the customer. It should look like this:

```
rewrite ^/news/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ /news_dett.php?l=$1&par=$2&titolo=$3 last;
```

Optionally placed inside a `location /news { ... }` block.

It is not clear from your question as to the value of `$1` in the second rewrite rule (I am assuming that it is empty). An alternative to an exact match `rewrite` directive would be an exact match location:

```
location = /Research-and-develop.html {
    rewrite ^ /researchdevelop?l= last;
}
```

See also [`rewrite` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite), [`location` documentaion](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), and a useful [regular expression resource](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html).